# WatchKit app loads indefinitely on Apple Watch, then crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, testflight, ipa

This is an issue people have had for a while, but I'm wondering if anybody has figured anything out recently - all the [discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8806) peters out around October 2015.

Basically, when I try to run a WatchKit app on the Watch (after running it succesfully on the simulator), it shows the loading daisy for a few minutes, then crashes.

I have tried:

- Building directly to iPhone with a paired Watch
- Exporting an ad-hoc .ipa and install on iPhone via iTunes
- Uploading a build to Testflight and installing on iPhone
- Every imaginable combination of restarting, unpairing/repairing, etc.

And I've tried all this with empty test projects, both Swift and Objective-C. Nothing has worked.

It's frustrating not to be able to test on the physical device. Has anybody figured out a workaround?

Comment: Have you checked the Devices pane and viewed your phone's device log for your watch app's crash report?

Comment: @PetahChristian I've tried, but for some reason no crash report appears (and I can see reports from other watch apps). The watch app simply stops running the loading animation, and returns to the clock screen (so maybe it never gets a chance to actually crash, because it never began loading?).

Comment: Nothing appears in the console. And when I try to manually attach the debugger to the watch, I get the Xcode alert `Could not launch 'watch'. / unable to attach`. (And yes, "Show App on Apple Watch" is enabled in the iOS Watch app.)

Comment: @PetahChristian Yes to my main app (although none of the keys discussed in that thread), but I've also tried clean test projects with identical results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My last ditch effort seems to have worked - I reformatted my computer and installed El Capitan and the production version of Xcode, and now I can build to the watch.

It's worth noting that I also upgraded to WatchOS 2.1 (from 2.0.1), which could be the actual reason it's working now, but I have no way of knowing.

Comment: What version of Xcode where you using?  It may have been a combination of that and older versions of watchOS/iOS.  There have been a lot of issue with connection and debugging on the watch.  Also, where you leaving the watch on the charger?  That improves connection quite a bit.  Can you mark your comments as answered?  That way this question will show as resolved.

Comment: I was on Xcode 7.2 (although I also tried the 7.3 beta). Yes, I did leave the watch on the charger (also with 100% battery) as part of my tests. I clicked the green checkmark on my answer - is that not showing up? Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options which might help resolve the issue:

- [File a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to bring this to the attention of the Apple Watch team.  As you may know, the more reports an issue receives, the higher its internal priority.
- Submit an Apple [Technical Support Incident](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) and work with an Apple engineer to identify and resolve the issue. *Note that Developer Technical Support will only assist you if you are not using beta software.  Don't test the beta, if you want assistance via this channel.*
- [Download watchOS](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/download/) 2.2 beta 2 (and Xcode 7.3 beta) to see if it resolves the issue. If not, file a bug report for the beta, as Apple will try to address as many beta issues as possible before general release.

  *Naturally, you should only beta test new software if your watch, phone, and computer aren't a primary (business-critical) device.*

If you can't obtain a solution via other channels, opening a TSI would be your most expedient option.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did file a radar a few days ago, and I have already tried the betas to no avail. I'm going to try one last shot in the dark - reformatting my computer, in case Xcode has some old library file or something from a previous install. If that doesn't work, I'll try a TSI (which I hadn't known about).

Comment: So I got it to work after reformatting my computer and upgrading to the current production build of WatchOS (2.1 - I had been on 2.0.1). I don't know which of those is the reason, but thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A possible option is that you configured a Interface Controller wrong in your storyboard.

If you experience the symptoms you described, you can do the following:

1. Open your Interface Storyboards of the WatchKit App one by one
2. Go to each Interface Controller and open the Identity Inspector
3. Make sure the Module selected in the Identity Inspector is your WatchKit Extension target (or in whatever target you have created your Interface Controller implementation).

[image: The "Identity Inspector" is the middle button in the panel on the right]